# rn-fetch-blob ask for storage automatically

Tags: react-native

I tried to download pdf file with rn-fetch-blob, first thing I add permissions in **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
```

then I use this code:

```
_downloadFile2 = () => {
  let DownloadDir = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DownloadDir
  let options = {
    fileCache: true,
    addAndroidDownloads : {
      useDownloadManager : true,
      notification : true,
      title : "file name",
      path: DownloadDir + '/' + "fileName"+ '.' + 'pdf',
      description : 'download fileName'
    }
  }
  RNFetchBlob.config(options)
  .fetch('GET', 'link....')
  .catch((err) => {console.warn('error' + err)})
};
```

my code works fine but I have to set STORAGE PERMISSION manually, what I want is to ask for storage automatically like when I want to use camera I had put this permission and it show me alert with an allow button, I don't know why it doesn't work with storage !

Second think is that I can't download my file 2 times. firt time (after allowed storage permission manually) it works fine but whene I click on button to redownload it I have an error or it deosn't anything it depends on the emulator
error what I have is: 
 1. message alert with 'download unsuccessful'
 2. I console.wanr error and I have this: `Error: Download manager failed to download from 'link...' Status Code = 16`

I think there is something with cach, but I don't know what to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To manually ask for permission:

```js
import { PermissionsAndroid, Platform } from 'react-native'

_downloadFile2 = async () => {
  if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    await PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    await PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
  }
}
// rest of the code
```

Also, remember, on iOS you don't have `fs.dirs.DownloadDir`, you should use `fs.dirs.DocumentDir` for iOS only.

Comment: I got an error: can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function

Comment: @zedArt sorry, I forgot the `async` keyword in the declaration of function, i just updated the code

Comment: what can I do to allow user download file many times ? or tell him tha file is already downloaded ?

Comment: @zedArt you can check if file is already downloaded by using `fs.exists('PATH_OF_FILE')` or `fs.stat('PATH_OF_FILE')` and look for `size` key into the returned object. What do you mean with "what can I do to allow user download file many times" ?  And please, upvote the above answer if it was useful for you! Thanks

Comment: thanks you i upvoted it. what I mean is allow user to download pdf file averytime he click on the button, because now it's possible juste first time he click on download button. when he click second time I got an error : Download manager failed to download from 'link...' Status Code = 16 ! I know it's about fs.exist but I don't kwon how to fix it